# R bar_geom thousand separator in bars

Tags: r, separator, geom-bar, geom-text

I have a dataframe which consists of different rubrics and pageviews, like in the following example:

```
categories| pageviews
health    |  700000
recipes   |  1000000
diet      |  500000
```

Now I plot it with the following code to get a barchart:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(reorder(pagePathLevel1, -pageviews), pageviews))
p + geom_bar(fill = "#00CC33", stat = "identity") +
  labs(x="categories", y="pageviews") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=pageviews), size=4, vjust = 1.2, color = "darkgreen")
```

Unfortunately, the scale_y_continuoius function only applies to the axis scale, but not to the values in geom_text. Is it possible to also get the thousand separator in the values displayed in the bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the column underlying your `label` aesthetic before drawing the plot, like this:

```
library(scales)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(label.pageviews = gsub("\\,",".", scales::comma(pageviews)))
```

This essentially uses the `comma` function from the `scales` package to insert the separators. Since you want dots instead of commas, the `gsub` part replaces one with the other.

You then only need to replace the old `label` aesthetic with the newly generated column, and then should get something like this:

```
 p + geom_bar(fill = "#00CC33", stat = "identity") +
               labs(x="categories", y="pageviews") +
               scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE)) +
               geom_text(aes(label=label.pageviews), size=4, vjust = 1.2, color = "darkgreen")
```

[image]